# Why does ng-mouseover not work with ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-show, angularjs-ng-if

I'm trying to use "ng-mouseover" directive on an image that has "ng-if" and it doesn't work but If I use "ng-show" directive it works, can everyone tell me why? Or it's an AngularJS problem?

In the AngularJS documentation, I can't read anything about it: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseover

ng-show

```
<button ng-show="true" ng-mouseover="countOne = countOne + 1" ng-init="countOne=0">
Increment (when mouse is over)
</button>
Count: {{countOne}}
```

ng-if

```
<button ng-if="true" ng-mouseover="countTwo = countTwo + 1" ng-init="countTwo=0">
Increment (when mouse is over)
</button>
Count: {{countTwo}}
```

Fiddle: http://plnkr.co/edit/Wb6bjyJdHj5qoH7fxGFJ?p=info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviour you're observing is caused by how `ngIf` works - [from the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

> Note that when an element is removed using ng-if its scope is destroyed
>   and a new scope is created when the element is restored. The scope
>   created within ngIf inherits from its parent scope using prototypal
>   inheritance. An important implication of this is if ngModel is used
>   within ngIf to bind to a javascript primitive defined in the parent
>   scope. In this case any modifications made to the variable within the
>   child scope will override (hide) the value in the parent scope.

Which basically means that you need to use `$parent` if you're using `ng-if`. Like so:

```
<button ng-if="true" ng-mouseover="$parent.countTwo = countTwo + 1" ng-init="$parent.countTwo=0">
```

Answer (score 1):

`ng-if` like other directives creates a child scope. Your code requires a `$parent` to point to your desired scope.

try something like this:

```
<p>
  <button ng-if="true" ng-mouseover="$parent.countTwo = countTwo + 1" ng-init="$parent.countTwo=0">
    Increment (when mouse is over)
  </button>
  Count: {{countTwo}}
</p>
```

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bYTe0xV5MjMB7D7SiNkz?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ng-if` so you have to use `$parent`

working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NhMKriotubvtBe7YmDgE?p=preview)

ng-if

```
<button ng-if="true" ng-mouseover="$parent.countTwo = countTwo + 1" ng-init="$parent.countTwo=0">
Increment (when mouse is over)
</button>
Count: {{countTwo}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because $event is outside the scope of that binding.

```
here is an example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Wb6bjyJdHj5qoH7fxGFJ?p=preview
```